# Number of new questions in a tag since you last viewed it

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

I think it would be a very helpful feature if for each of your favourited tags you could see the number of questions that have been asked since you viewed the page for that tag's questions.

I always have to keep multiple tabs open - one for the main page, one for every tag I want - to make sure I see any new questions that have been asked. It would be a large convenience if I could have just one page open and see how many new questions have been asked in my favourited tags' categories since I last viewed that category. Something like the thing that shows you that you have some unread responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you subscribe to the RSS feed for a tag like [templates](/questions/tagged/templates) with [RSS Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/templates) then you will get this behavior.

For those of us with tons of tags added to the favorite, ignored, etc, this would be very distracting.

Further, (in my minimal understanding of ASP design), I think this could place a huge burden on the Stack Exchange resources and would quickly be status-declined -- similar to how latex markdown is not supported on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Oh cool, what's a good RSS reader to use?

Comment: I just use the Firefox live bookmarks.  But most here prefer Chrome.  You might try looking on http://stackapps.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar with the Stack Exchange custom filter mechanism.

For example, my [Small Tags/sites](https://stackexchange.com/filters/19305/small-tags-sites) filter shows all questions in my elected tags and sites. Whenever I (logged in) reload the page, it highlights the questions which are new/have activity (depending on the tab) since the last view.

Make your filter with only one tag on one site, and you have what you want.